# How can I flatten an array targeting only specified children?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a collection that looks similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "id": 200244,
        "siblings": []
    }, {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "id": 200134,
        "siblings": []
    }, {
        "name": "Item 3",
        "id": 200179,
        "siblings": [
            {
                "name": "Item 3 SubItem 1",
                "id": 200146
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "name": "Item 4",
        "id": 200133,
        "siblings": []
    }, {
        "name": "Item 5",
        "id": 200135,
        "siblings": [
            {
                "name": "Item 5 SubItem 1",
                "id": 200146
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I’m trying to flatten this so that the child `siblings` values are pulled up a level *only* when they aren’t empty. The end structure would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "id": 200244
    }, {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "id": 200134
    }, {
        "name": "Item 3",
        "id": 200179
    }, {
        "name": "Item 3 SubItem 1",
        "id": 200146
    }, {
        "name": "Item 4",
        "id": 200133
    }, {
        "name": "Item 5",
        "id": 200135
    }, {
        "name": "Item 5 SubItem 1",
        "id": 200146
    }
]
```

Suggestions on where to get started with this? I’ve toyed with Lodash’s `flatMap` without success.

Comment: Does order matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking `flatMap` is the right choice

```
const data =
  ...

const flatMap = (f, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, x) => acc.concat (f (x)), [])

flatMap (({ siblings = [], ...item }) => [ item, ...siblings ], data)
// [ { name: 'Item 1', id: 200244 }
// , { name: 'Item 2', id: 200134 }
// , { name: 'Item 3', id: 200179 }
// , { name: 'Item 3 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// , { name: 'Item 4', id: 200133 }
// , { name: 'Item 5', id: 200135 }
// , { name: 'Item 5 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// ]
```

Using lodash's `_.flatMap` is almost identical to our implementation above - only the order of the arguments is switched

```
const data =
  ...

const result = 
  _.flatMap ( data
            , ({ siblings = [], ...item }) => [ item, ...siblings ]
            )

console.log (result)
// [ { name: 'Item 1', id: 200244 }
// , { name: 'Item 2', id: 200134 }
// , { name: 'Item 3', id: 200179 }
// , { name: 'Item 3 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// , { name: 'Item 4', id: 200133 }
// , { name: 'Item 5', id: 200135 }
// , { name: 'Item 5 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// ]
```

Here's a full program demonstration using the `flatMap` implementation provided here. Feel free to use it or any other implementation of your choosing :)

```js
const flatMap = (f, xs = []) =>
  xs.reduce ((acc, x) => acc.concat (f (x)), [])
  
const data =
  [ { name: "Item 1"
    , id: 200244
    , siblings: []
    }
  , { name: "Item 2"
    , id: 200134
    , siblings: []
    }
  , { name: "Item 3"
    , id: 200179
    , siblings:
      [ { name: "Item 3 SubItem 1"
        , id: 200146
        }
      ]
    }
  , { name: "Item 4"
    , id: 200133
    , siblings: []
    }
  , { name: "Item 5"
    , id: 200135
    , siblings:
      [ { name: "Item 5 SubItem 1"
        , id: 200146
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

const result = 
  flatMap (({ siblings = [], ...item }) => [ item, ...siblings ], data)

console.log (result)
// [ { name: 'Item 1', id: 200244 }
// , { name: 'Item 2', id: 200134 }
// , { name: 'Item 3', id: 200179 }
// , { name: 'Item 3 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// , { name: 'Item 4', id: 200133 }
// , { name: 'Item 5', id: 200135 }
// , { name: 'Item 5 SubItem 1', id: 200146 }
// ]
```

Comment: What is that all about?

Comment: Someone, presumably another answerer, did not like the other solutions provided

Comment: Good stuff in here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could create recursive function with Lodash `reduce()` and `pick()` methods to flatten array of any depth.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Item 1","id":200244,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 2","id":200134,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 3","id":200179,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 3 SubItem 1","id":200146}]},{"name":"Item 4","id":200133,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 5","id":200135,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 5 SubItem 1","id":200146}]}]

const flatten = data => {
  return _.reduce(data, (r, e) => {
    r.push(_.pick(e, ['name', 'id']))
    if (e.siblings) r.push(...flatten(e.siblings))
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(flatten(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` and use `concat` to add the siblings

```js
let arr=[{"name":"Item 1","id":200244,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 2","id":200134,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 3","id":200179,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 3 SubItem 1","id":200146}]},{"name":"Item 4","id":200133,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 5","id":200135,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 5 SubItem 1","id":200146}]}];

let result = arr.reduce((c, {siblings,...r}) => {
  c.push(r);                    //Push the {name,id}
  c = c.concat(siblings);       //Concat the siblings
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash's [`_.flatMapDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatMapDeep) with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring):

```js
const data = [{"name":"Item 1","id":200244,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 2","id":200134,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 3","id":200179,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 3 SubItem 1","id":200146}]},{"name":"Item 4","id":200133,"siblings":[]},{"name":"Item 5","id":200135,"siblings":[{"name":"Item 5 SubItem 1","id":200146}]}];

const result= _.flatMapDeep(data, ({ siblings, ...rest }) => [rest, siblings]);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm guessing you picked `flatMapDeep` to support data that nests beyond 1 level?

Comment: @user633183 - No. I need to flatten more than one level because siblings is an array as well. You've flattened it with spread `[item, ...siblings]`, and I'm using flatMapDeep instead.

Comment: Why not just `[ item ].concat(siblings)` then?

Comment: Because that's what [`_.flatMapDeep()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatMapDeep) is for - "it recursively flattens the mapped results."

Answer (score 0):

Granted it's not using Lodash or more modern JS techniques, but here is a simple way to lift and shift. Doesn't account for ordering either..

```js
var json = [{
  "name": "Item 1",
  "id": 200244,
  "siblings": []
}, {
  "name": "Item 2",
  "id": 200134,
  "siblings": []
}, {
  "name": "Item 3",
  "id": 200179,
  "siblings": [{
    "name": "Item 3 SubItem 1",
    "id": 200146
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Item 4",
  "id": 200133,
  "siblings": []
}, {
  "name": "Item 5",
  "id": 200135,
  "siblings": [{
    "name": "Item 5 SubItem 1",
    "id": 200146
  }]
}];

for (var obj in json) {
  var nestedObj = json[obj];
  if (nestedObj.hasOwnProperty('siblings')) {
    if (nestedObj.siblings.length > 0) {
      for (var sibling in nestedObj.siblings) {
        var siblingItem = nestedObj.siblings[sibling];
        json.push(siblingItem);
      }
    }
    delete nestedObj['siblings'];
  }
}

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? He said he tried with Lodash, without success, this is just an alternate way of doing things...

Comment: Someone came through and downvoted *everything*. No idea why.